# Ninject Context Uniqueness

Tags: .net, ninject

I'm writing a Ninject extension and have some questions about the internals of Ninject.  Is the following true?

1. It seems like each activated instance has a distinct IContext associated with it.
2. Contexts cannot be recycled.  Once the object associated w a context has been created (ie the `IObject` in `Bind<IObject>.To...`), that context cannot be reused to create another object.  The next time the binding is resolved, it will use a newly created context.

Comment: Regarding 2.: I think you are right, however, consider that a context may have a parent context and the parent-context's parameters (constructor arguments etc.) are reused when resolving the "child". Also, when using the ContextPreservation extension the original context is used as parent context when a factory (can be as simple as Func<IFoo>) instanciates a new object at a later time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Context gives you the context information for the currently activated object. E.g. what type, where it will be injected into, ....

This information is different for every activated object, So yes a new instance will be created for each activated object. Also the context is created before the object is activated.

Comment: I'm writing an extension like your Dependency Creation plugin (I used a lot of the same code).  The difference is that it queues the types to activate until the object has been resolved down to the resolution root.  Its definitely a work in progress.  The bulk of the logic is in "CreateOnActivationActivationStrategy.cs".  https://github.com/orourkedd/ninject.extensions.createonactivation

Comment: You are doing that way to complicated. You don't have to track transient. OnActivation is called exactly once for each activated instance. Get the root like https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.namedscope/blob/master/src/Ninject.Extensions.NamedScope/NamedScopeExtensionMethods.cs InCallScope. Add the directives for all that are not root to your dictionary (Use lock or ConcurrentDictionary!) Solve the problem that the same directive is added several times when activating the root (list.Distinct()).

Comment: The idea is to queue all directives for dependencies until the root is activated.  The problem I had was that sometimes the resolution root has already been resolved (in the case of lazy-loading). In this case I have to determine if an object's ancestor has already been activated.  This is what the transient cache is for.  I also don't want to have to use a special scope for dependencies.